# INSERT in table1 based on condition on table2 - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `t1` and `t2` in MySQL. I've to insert records into `t1` when the following conditions on `t2` are `TRUE`: `version != -1 AND login = "xyz"`.

I tried this query but no luck:

```
INSERT INTO t1(name, login, email, add)
SELECT "john", "john159", "jj@abc.com", "dallas"
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT version, login 
FROM t2
WHERE login = "john159" 
AND version != -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following, I haven't executed the same on the editor but I hope you will get a different idea with it.

```
INSERT INTO T1(name, login, email) 
        SELECT "john", "john159", "j@a.com"
            FROM dual
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2
                                 WHERE login = "john159" 
                                   AND version  <> -1)
```